# Nested loop repeating itself most likely because of incorrect booleann operators c++

Tags: c++, console-application, nested-loops, do-while

My problem is that the second do while loop repeats itself if I type in anything other then a 1. If I type in a 1 when it asks if I'm sure it exits the loop but any other number just makes the console window continue repeating its question without giving me the chance to answer. I've only been C++ for less then a week but I think that these lines are the problem.

`} while ( x != 2 || 1);`
`} while (x != 1);`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
struct adress{
    string name;
    string adress;
    int phonenumber;
};
adress fillform()
{
    int x;
    adress form;
    do{
        cout << "What's your name" << endl;
        cin >> form.name;
        cout << "What's your adress" << endl;
        cin >> form.adress;
        cout << "What's your phone number" << endl;
        cin >> form.phonenumber;
        cout << "Your name is " << form.name << endl;
        cout << "Your adress is " << form.adress << endl;
        cout << "Your phone number is " << form.phonenumber << endl;
        do{
            cout << "Is this information correct?\n1. Yes 2. No" << endl;
            cin >> x;
            switch ( x )
            {
            case 1:
                cout << "Okay" << endl;
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << "Try again" << endl;
            default:
                cout << "Invalid answer" << endl;
            }
        } while ( x != 2 || 1);
    } while (x != 1);
    return form;
}
int main()
{
    fillform();
}
```

Comment: You probably wanted `while ( x != 2 && x !=1);`.

Comment: My ex-wife used to do the same thing.

Comment: @thesudoer You also missed a `break;` statement before default.

Comment: Just realized yeah thankyou :)

Answer (score 2):

`x != 2 || 1` stands for `(x != 2) || 1` which is always true.

You need `x != 2 && x != 1`.

Answer (score 1):

`x != 2 || 1` means

- when "x is not two" is true, or
- when 1 is true

(or both).

True and false equate to 1 and 0 respectively, so 1 is always true.

What I imagine you actually wanted was

`x != 2 && x != 1`, which means

- when x is not two, and
- when x is also not 1

You might want to look into [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) to work out which operators apply first, and also bear in mind that you need to have a *complete evaluable phrase* between each operator. In other words, if you want "X is A or B", you will need to say "X is A or X is B".

Answer (score 0):

Check your operator precedence (here is a relevant snippet of the table).

Your "!=" binds before the "||", making the expression always true

( (x != 2) || 1) becomes just (1)

That explains the problem you are seeing. If you really want to check all the precedence rules or take a print-copy, here is the link : [C++ operator precedence table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

```
9   ==   != For relational = and ≠ respectively
10  &   Bitwise AND
11  ^   Bitwise XOR (exclusive or)
12  |   Bitwise OR (inclusive or)
13  &&  Logical AND
14  ||  Logical OR
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is at 1 because 1 is always true and whan 1 is ORed with something it is always going to be true.